# mounting bongos skin: which side

Tags: percussion, bongos

I am replacing a bongos skin and I know that the smooth side of the skin should the one to play on.

Problem is that I forgot to check and now the skin is already wet and both sides are smooth.

However I can tell by the darker spots of the skin which side was actually the external one when it was on the animal. I can also say the supposed inner side is kind of velvet.

On which side would you play?

(PS: the skin has no hair)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I post what worked in my case, inferring it might be true in general. Please feel free to post a better answer or to improve this one.*

**You play on the external side.** Although the inner one was smooth and velvet, drying it became more rough.